# Ruby loop until gets issue

Tags: ruby

Reclarification on the original question. I need a loop that will run in ruby and allow me to enter the commmand stop into the console (using gets perhaps) and then the loop will stop.

Cheers
Martin

Comment: You should add a few more tags (e.g. <code>until</code> or <code>loop</code>) so that if others have this same problem, they can find this question.

Comment: I think it's fine that the question doesn't include more tags, nothing more than pure Ruby is involved here. Tags like `loop` should be avoided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could use something like this:

```
# Initialize the input queue. This is where the user-created info will be stored
$QUEUE = []
def pending
  old = $QUEUE
  $QUEUE = []
  old
end

t = Thread.new do
  loop do
    # Ask the user for something
    print "Enter info here: "
    # Read information in
    $QUEUE << gets.chomp
  end
end

# Example code utilizing this; you can do whatever you like with the queue
2.times do
  sleep 5
  # Print the list out
  puts "\nYou entered: \n" << pending.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: You could also just use `exit` instead of `Thread.main.exit`.

Comment: I think you confuse [`Kernel#exit`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/exit) with [`Thread.exit`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Thread/exit/class) here. `exit` will just terminate the complete script, which seems appropriate. Your additional piece of logic in the third example can be implemented a bit cleaner by not setting a variable and just checking for `t.stop?` inside the main loop.

Comment: Ah, I see. As for `Thread#running?`, I can't believe I forgot about that... :P Changing; thanks!

Comment: Another tip: use backticks (`\``) to mark inline code :P Oh, and it's `.alive?` or in this case, `.stop?`, I just looked it up.

Comment: Ah, so _thats_ how you mark code in comments... hah! Anyway, I just realized that simply exiting won't work in all cases; it will do that if an error occurs somewhere inside, but most errors won't set `should_stop` to true.

Comment: It's "good enough" for the purposes (and your sample suffers from the same issue). One could easily enclose the `gets` call into a `begin`/`ensure` block. The method using `break if t.stop?` should work in all cases, though.

Comment: Another tip... maybe the OP wants to use the `gets` string, and stop when its content is `"stop"`.

Comment: @Niklas B. Hmm, I just tested this. It appears you are correct yet again. Also, you said "your sample suffers from the same issue". How so? --- EDIT: Should we move to chat? SO is complaining.

Comment: @SonySantos: OP didn't ask for that, but it would be trivial to do: Just use `loop { line = gets.chomp ; break if line == 'stop' }`.

Comment: @Jwosty: I don't like the chat. It's fine now.

Comment: @SonySantos: This is equivalent to the first chunk of code in the answer, and I don't think its quite what the OP wants because the loop will execute once, wait for the user to type something, execute and so on... The last example doesn't wait between steps.

Comment: Indeed, if that can be resolved that would be awesome as that is the question, cheers tho jwosty

Comment: Oh okay, this is a little more complex, but not impossible!

Comment: Sweet Jwosty, will await your next answer with anticipation judging by your 1st! :)

Comment: Sorry, I was busy up until now. I'll see if I can post anything. :)

Comment: Jwosty, I am still needing this issue resolved, if you can check the updated question and assist that would be amazing, or anyone else :) thanks, martin

Comment: @marscom Oh, I forgot to tell you that I updated it. I think. If this doesn't work, please tell me.